# Traits with defs that take the same concrete type

Tags: scala, traits

I'm trying to make a class hierarchy of types that share common functions, but only when used together.

```
sealed trait Farm[S <: Farm[S]] { 
  def animals: Int
  def +(other: S) = animals + other.animals
}

case class SheepFarm(animals: Int) extends Farm[SheepFarm]
case class GoatFarm(animals: Int) extends Farm[GoatFarm]

object Tester {

  val total = SheepFarm(5) + SheepFarm(6) // should return 11
  val failure = SheepFarm(5) + GoatFarm(3) // should not compile

  // should be able to use this pattern for functions outside the main classes
  def add[S <: Farm[S]](one: S, two: S) = one + two
  val total2 = add(SheepFarm(5), SheepFarm(6)) // should return 11
  val failure2 = add(SheepFarm(5), GoatFarm(3)) // should not compile
}
```

So far, this awkward `Foo[S <: Foo[S]]`  construction is the only way I've found to do this, which makes a lot of code downstream less readable.  Is there any more elegant way to do get this pattern to work, so I can just pass around `Foo`s?

I've tried various permutations of implicit parameters, `this.type`, and type parameters, but have had no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic "self type" problem with many solutions, each one having its own drawbacks.

There are several resources and discussions about this, a good place to start is [this Jessica Kerr's blog post](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/02/when-oo-and-fp-meet-mytype-problem.html) (also, look at more resources she listed there).

I once found an alternative solution for this problem that uses whitebox macros. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ghik/selftyped).